# How do I use encryption when calling GetDocument from the DocuSign Rest API

Tags: docusignapi

I need to encrypt documents when downloading them using the GetDocument function in C#. When I set the "encrypt" Document Option to "true" as a parameter, I get an exception that no security appliance is configured? I don't know if that means I'm supposed to purchase a physical security appliance? Am I going down the wrong path or is the download transmission already secure?

var docOptions = new GetDocumentOptions();
docOptions.encrypt = "true";

MemoryStream docStream = (MemoryStream)envelopeApi.GetDocument(AccountID, envelope.EnvelopeId, doc.DocumentId, docOptions);

The exception I get is:
"errorCode": "NO_SECURITY_APPLIANCES_CONFIGURED"

Answer (score 1):

The download transmission itself is already secured by TLS. The `encrypt` flag allows you to specify whether or not a DocuSign Security Appliance should be used to encrypt the file that will be at rest.

The Security Appliance is a separate purchase that allows you to maintain your own private keys to restrict access to documents held in DocuSign. If that is something that sounds relevant to you, I'd recommend reaching out to your Account Manager.